# "Name 'Url' is not declared" when I try to use Url.Content()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, migration

I have an ASP.NET site that is not currently using MVC but I'm trying to convert it to MVC slowly.  The first time I tried using **Url.Content** in an .aspx page I got:

```
Name 'Url' is not declared
```

I then added:

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

and:

```
<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
```

to the appropriate places in the **web.config** file, but it had no effect.

Comment: I assume you added a reference to System.Web.Mvc in your project?

Comment: That does the same thing as adding the "assembly" tag to web.config, which I did manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page needs to inherit from ViewPage so you'll need a page directive like this at the top of the aspx page...

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

Also, not sure if you've seen it but this article by Maarten Balliauw might help :-)

http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc